# How to insert just few words in WooCommerce translated strings

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, translation, gettext

Searching how to modify just a few words in the «new account» WooCommerce email to customer. I'm building WooCommerce shop in French, but it will be multilanguage.

I have to make this change in the theme for this new account mail and also for the «my account» page.

I Need to change the phrase in the new account mail to customer like this:
…vos commandes, **créer ou** changer votre… 
where "créer ou" is inserted.

And in the «my account» page: 
…ainsi que **créer ou** changer votre… 
where "créer ou" is inserted.

Please take a look at the screenshots:

WooCommerce email notification - new account to customer:

[image]

WooCommerce wording in my account page:

[image]

i have tried to edit the specific woocommerce template in the theme code, but if change this words in english because the template is in english, its generating a email in english. So making changes there keeping the translation options is over my basic knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following, to insert a string into some translated strings:

```php
add_filter( 'gettext', 'customize_woocommerce_translated_strings', 10, 3 );
function customize_woocommerce_translated_strings( $translated_text, $original_text, $domain ) {
    // Not in cart or checkout pages
    $targeted_string1 = 'changer votre mot de passe et les détails de votre compte';
    $targeted_string2 = 'changer votre mot de passe, et plus encore ici';
    $string_to_insert = 'créer ou ';

    if( is_account_page() && strpos( $translated_text, $targeted_string1) !== false ) {
        $translated_text = str_replace($targeted_string1, $string_to_insert.$targeted_string1, $translated_text);
    }

    if( ! is_admin() && strpos( $translated_text, $targeted_string2) !== false ) {
        $translated_text = str_replace($targeted_string2, $string_to_insert.$targeted_string2, $translated_text);
    }

    return $translated_text;
}
```

Code goes on functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

On my account dashboard:

[image]

On New account email notification:

[image]

Note: You can also use [Loco Translate plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/) to change translated strings.

Comment: oups, waht happens ? site is blank after enter this code with code snippet plugin ???

https://tentacio.myhostpoint.ch/

Comment: @jean-christophe I have tested again the code, and I don't have any issue. The words "créer ou" are correctly inserted in my account dashboard and in new account email notification.

Comment: You just need to replace the database from a backup. To avoid this kind of issues, don't use Code Snippets plugin, instead, use a child theme (+ an FTP software and a code editor). A child theme also allows deeper customizations as files and templates overriding, which is useful for WooCommerce.

Comment: this code works perfectely added to functions.php on a child theme